Using ecrecover returns incorrect signer only for specific data (approx 0.3% of cases)
In my tests for a contract that uses ecrecover to verify certain data, I am doing 100,000 iterations of checking that the ecrecover func returns the address matching the signer when using random data.
Bizarrely, it returns an incorrect signer approximately 300 / 100,000 times. I am using hardhat with ethers. It is consistent in which data causes it to fail, ie the same data will always cause a failure, regardless of signer.
The data being signed is just an address, string, uint. I had the same issue with an address and two uints.
An example of failing data is:
0xa0Ee7A142d267C1f36714E4a8F75612F20a79720 
"ED_ZEY"
42648 

I tried using my contract in Remix in case it was something to do with hardhat, but it also returned an incorrect signer specifically for that data.
Below is the js for how I am signing the message:
const createSignature = async(
    _player,
    _action,
    _nonce
) =>{
    const messageHash = await createMessageHash( 
        _player,
        _action,
        _nonce
    );
    return await signMessage(messageHash);
}
const createMessageHash = async(
    _player,
    _action,
    _nonce
)=>{
    return await ethers.solidityPackedKeccak256(
        ["address", "string" , "uint256"],
        [
            _player,
            _action,
            _nonce
        ]
    );
}
const signMessage = async(message) =>{

    const binary = await ethers.toBeArray(message);

    return await account.signMessage(binary);
}

I can not work out why it's only failing for specific input data. Changing the integer or address by 1, or changing the string by a single character stops it from failing. However a signer that fails 0.3% of the time is still too often.

The failure rate smells like it could be leading zero case or such packing error

my suspicion was that it was something related to packing, but i'm at a loss at how to debug it without getting deep into ethersjs or solidity (depending where the packing error is occuring)

I debugged a similar bug long time ago. What I did that I run the same function in Solidity smart contract by calling a contract function and then JS. I compared the inputs and outputs and then traced the problem down to the broken way how JS handled some cases. Because JS does not have real binary types and tend to use hex strings everywhere, it is an unholy mess where you do not want to stick your finger in.

I did compare my ethers.solidityPackedKeccak256 with a solidity function doing keccak256(abi.encodePacked on the same data (first step in deriving signer on-chain) and they give the same data. Actually compared all steps to the on-chain stuff up until actually calling ecrecover and they are identical. Unless they aren't actually identical and my js is doing some sort of implicit conversion.

In your signMessage function, to get the bytes (Uint8Array) representation of the messageHash, you need to use the ethers.getBytes function instead of ethers.toBeArray, like:
const signMessage = async (message) => {

    const binary = ethers.getBytes(message);

    return await account.signMessage(binary);
}

Then, the signer can be recovered as:
JS
const recoverSigner = (messageHash, signature) => {
    return ethers.verifyMessage(
        ethers.getBytes(messageHash),
        signature
    );
}

Solidity (Using ecrecover)
function getSigner(bytes32 _hash, bytes memory _signature) public pure returns (address) {
    bytes32 r;
    bytes32 s;
    uint8 v;
    if (_signature.length != 65) {
        return address(0);
    }
    assembly {
        r := mload(add(_signature, 32))
        s := mload(add(_signature, 64))
        v := byte(0, mload(add(_signature, 96)))
    }
    if (v < 27) {
        v += 27;
    }
    if (v != 27 && v != 28) {
        return address(0);
    } else {
        return ecrecover(keccak256(abi.encodePacked("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32", _hash)), v, r, s);
    }
}

Solidity (Using Openzeppelin ECDSA)
function getSignerUsingOpenzeppelin(bytes32 _hash, bytes memory _signature) public pure returns (address) {
    return ECDSA.recover(keccak256(abi.encodePacked("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32", _hash)), _signature);
}


both solutions provided (ecrecover and ECDSA) using non-packed data for hashing also return a similar fail rate.
an example of failing data:
0x2546BcD3c84621e976D8185a91A922aE77ECEc30, "OUJ", 692724

Thanks for pointing out. I've edited my answer by adding more details and correction. Basically, the problem was in using ethers.toBeArray instead of ethers.getBytes. So, when you use ethers.getBytes to get the bytes array representation of the message hash, then the correct signature would be generated and the same during the verification (in JS).

@AnAllergyToAnalogy, you can also refer to this gist. I've created a Foundry Fuzz Test for the same.

So it seems the only necessary change was from ethers.toBeArray to ethers.getBytes, once I made this change the error rate went down to 0% regardless of whether I'm using encode or encodePacked. If you update your answer to just focus on the ethers change I will market it as correct.

@AnAllergyToAnalogy, done.
